# How to exclude private events in laravel 5.5?

Tags: php, api, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I have this piece of legacy code to return all events to the front end:

```
/**
     * @param $request
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function index( EventsFilterRequest $request ) {
        $keys = $request->all();

        if ( \count( $keys ) === 0 ) {
            return $this->eventsQueryBuilder()->isVisibleFor( authUser()->id )->ofOrder( 'starts_at', 'ASC' )->ofCountry( runtime()->country()->id )->ofStatus( 'future' );
        }

        $events = $this->eventsQueryBuilder()->isVisibleFor( authUser()->id )->ofOrder( 'starts_at', 'ASC' )->ofStatus( 'future' )->ofCountry( runtime()->country()->id );
        foreach ( $keys as $key => $value ) {
            if ( array_key_exists( $key, $this->_methods ) ) {
                $events = $this->_methods[$key]( $events, $request, $this );
            }
        }

        return $events;
    }
```

In the `events` table there's a column called `privacy` that contains `public` or `private`. How can I exclude private events from being returned ?

Comment: I do not know laravel but have you tried to add an ->ofPrivacy('public') filter to your eventQueryBuilder chain?

Comment: No, but can you share more details ? what's the docs for this function.

Comment: It was just a wild inference, as you have several function starting with of, followed by what appear to be a column name, and with a single parameter [e.g. ofStatus, ofCountry] maybe there is in place a ofPrivacy function that do what you need (otherwise I would create it using the ofStatus one as example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am new to laravel but you can use where clause in your query. Something like

`$events = DB::table('events')->where('privacy', 'public')->get();`

For more check this link [LARAVEL QUERY](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries)